# Serialized JSON VS XML in terms of Performance

Tags: php, xml, json, optimization

I'm on a PHP environment and I'm receiving data from some API in `XML` format. I'm storing them in local storage instead of a database. I do some some primary filtering and remove unnecessary data before storing them.

I need to decide in which format I should store them. [`JSON encoded txt` or `XML`]. Or should I leave them as they are.

**Which method will be better in terms of:**

1. less file size
2. fast decoding and encoding
3. less resource consumption

Comment: JSON is typically smaller in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's potentially no difference between storing a XML or JSON document on disk as you've to consider the 4Kb storing blocks (for normal hard disks). storing a 3Kb JSON will take same (real) space as storing 1Kb XML (4 KB actually).

the cost of IO operations are mainly the same.

in an other side, have a DOM representation of an XML document in memory will cost more than a simple JSON document (for same structure), at that point JSON is better.

decoding/encoding a XML depends on parsers (Stax is as far I remember the fastest).

Comment: Thanks a lot @AbderRazakk. Your answer illustrates what I needed. I was expecting more than one answer though. :)
Can you provide a little more details please? (some benchmarks, comparison maybe)...

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't had to bunch mark these situation yet but it's easy to do , just create a script that reads/write a bunch of xml files and writes to a disk to xml/json and try to log time between start/end and you'll have an idea. try to use sometimes small files sometimes big files. This'll give you a harsh estimation you can tune then.

Comment: I already did. I didn't log the time though, but I pursed a huge bunch of files (like 500) at once. I got JSON faster and smaller in size than xml. Thanks a lot. :D